# Javascript document.getElementById set input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I got some input validator, that checks if user e-mail and username not registered on website. My code looke like that:

Javascript:

```
    $(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#email').blur(function(event) {
        $.get(BaseUrl + 'auth/email/check/' + $(this).val(), function(data)
        {
            if (data == 1) {
                $('input#email').removeClass('valid');
                $('input#email').addClass('error');
                document.getElementById('div-error').style.display = "block";
            } else {
                document.getElementById('div-error').style.display = "none";
            }
        });
    });
            $('#username').blur(function(event) {
        $.get(BaseUrl + 'auth/username/check/' + $(this).val(), function(data)
        {
            if (data == 1) {
                $('input#username').removeClass('valid');
                $('input#username').addClass('error');
                document.getElementById('div-error').style.display = "block";
            } else {
                document.getElementById('div-error').style.display = "none";
            }
        });
    });
});
```

DIV code after username input:

```
<div id="div-error" style="display: none;">username has alerdy registered</div>
```

DIV code after e-mail input:

```
<div id="div-error" style="display: none;">email already registered</div>
```

But then username is not-registered and email already registered i'm getting error on all this 2 inputs... How can i set document.getElementById for special inputs?

Comment: ID must be **unique**, use class instead for similar elements. In your case(as HTML is not added), you can use different ids

Answer (score 0):

Your error-divs got the same id. An ID in HTML must be unique.
Try giving these elements classes like

```
<div class="div-error" id="div-error-username" style="display: none;">...</div>

<div class="div-error" id="div-error-email" style="display: none;">...</div>
```